# Using Bing mapping as a Google mapping overlay - anyone help update my code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bing-maps

this will sound a bit weak but... i've been using a lovely bit of javascript called "Google Maps OS" by Liam Corner that i got from a greasemonkey plugin http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/84975 (that no longer exists).

I've never really understood quite how the script worked, but it worked very well till a couple of weeks ago. Then the detailed Ordnance Survey mapping at 1:50000 and 1:25000 scales just disappeared, this was sourced from Bing mapping and overlaid on to my google mapping. The script now serves up some very bland map tiles that are no use for my purpose.

The important bit of the script that overlays the mapping looks like this...

```
    Create: function (){
    var customMapLayer ={
        getTileUrl: function (pos, zoom){
            var serverID = (((pos.y & 1) << 1) + (pos.x & 1));
            var URL = "http://ecn.t" + serverID + ".tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r";

            for (i = zoom - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                URL = URL + (((((pos.y >> i) & 1) << 1) + ((pos.x >> i) & 1)));
            }

            // OS tiles are only available for zoom levels 12 - 16, otherwise fall back to standard Bing map tiles
            if (zoom >= 12){
                URL = URL + ".png?g=41&productSet=mmOS";
            }else{
                URL = URL + "?g=550&shading=hill";
            }

            return URL;
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        isPng: true,
        maxZoom: 16,
        minZoom: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        name: "OS maps",
        alt: "OS 1:50k maps at Zoom 12-14, and 1:25k maps at Zoom 15-16"
    };
    window._gmaps_os_customMapType = new     google.maps.ImageMapType(customMapLayer);
    };
```

So is there any way to fix it so it can get the OS mapping?
I know that Bing hasn't completely withdrawn the Ordnance Survey mapping as i can sill see it on Bing maps - e.g. https://www.bing.com/mapspreview?v=2&cp=53.755093~-1.661820&lvl=15&sty=s&form=LMLTCC

Any suggestions?

Comment: take a look at leaflet, lets you get tiles from multiple sources

Comment: Hi Charlietfl - where might i find this leaflet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Ordnance Survey map data that is in Bing Maps outside of the Bing Maps controls is against the terms of use. A couple of weeks ago the tile server was locked down to prevent these tiles from being used outside the Bing Maps API. Note that the Ordnance Survey does not allow any of their data to be used with Google maps. Doing so is also against the Ordnance Survey terms of use.

Comment: Thanks - i assumed that might have been the issue